# spring async not releasing database connection

Tags: spring, multithreading, jooq, bonecp, spring-async

**Tech Stack** 
I am using spring boot 1.3.5 for a rest service which internally fetch the data from database..ORM used is JOOQ and the connection pool management is done by BoneCP...

**Requirement**
I have a requirement where i need to fire multiple sql to fetch the data ,combine the result and return them all together...

**ISSUE**
I have achieved this using spring async but ran into problem where the spring sync method held up database connection and does not release them to database pool..After few hits the max connection is reached and application stops responding ...

**try**
As soon as i remove the @Async annotation from my method it works fine ..

Please suggest a possible solution to this problem where i need to fire multiple query and combine the result.
Also another solution if someone help me if there is any settings in bonecp which release connections back to pool after timeout.

Comment: What is the reason for "spring sync method held up database connection"? is it long running processes?

Comment: the query is not long running..but the result is delivered but the database connection is not released back to pool

Comment: Didn't you call `connection.close()` to return connection to pool after executing queries?

Comment: as mentioned i as using boncep with spring boot and thus opening a connection and closing is handled automatically by database pool.i am opening a connection specifically and thus can not close connection.

Answer (score 0):

Consider following solutions. Then think what would fit in your application

1. Increase connection limit in DB
2. Decrease @Async threads to reduce usage of connection
3. Design your @Async block code to use certain amount of connections from pool. So the rest of connections will remain for other usage for application.

Comment: 1.Increase connection limit in DB -->this does not help as at some point of time the limit is raised. 2.Decrease @Async threads to reduce usage of connection --> this is always 3 can not decrease 3. Not sure how to do that... any help